# Python using regular expression, how to find second occurrence and in between of words in line

Tags: python, regex

For below text line, I want to find the parameter/ word between "AND" and "BETWEEN" i.e. I want lst_updt_ts to be retured

criteria1='where prcs_ts Between TO_DATE('01/01/2019 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('03/31/2019 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND lst_updt_ts BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2019 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('03/31/2019 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')'

re.findall('AND (.*) BETWEEN',criteria1)

When I use above code I am getting "AND TO_DATE('03/31/2019 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND lst_updt_ts " but I just need "lst_updt_ts". It is taking the first AND, But I want it take the just before AND of BETWEEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for this specific string, you want the last combination of `AND <column_name> BETWEEN`

```py
re.search(r'.*AND (.*) BETWEEN',criteria1).group(1)
```

Result:

```
lst_updt_ts
```

Comment: when I executed "re.search(r'.*AND (.*) BETWEEN',criteria1).group(1)" I got result as just "e" where as I have tried to put your logic in findall by changing to - re.findall(r'.*AND (.*) BETWEEN',criteria1) it resulted in "lst_updt_ts". It solved my problem. Thank You!